# Java EE 7 updatetool installation fails

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-7

I have tried to install Java EE 7 with updatetool to be able to run Java EE Tutorial examples.

But the installation of updatetool fails. I have tried to start updatetool installation from the command line on my elementary os, then I saw the error when installing updatetool.

Here is an image: http://oi58.tinypic.com/x6iumx.jpg

Error text example 1:

Input/output error: Connection failed for URL http://pkg.oracle.com/javaeesdk/7/native/release/manifest/0/updatetool@2.3.5%2C0-56.2852%3A20111207T211721Z: 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable

```
Could not download application packages. This could be because:
  - a proxy server is needed to access the internet. Please ensure that
    the system proxy server settings are correct, or set the 'http_proxy'
    environment variable to the full URL of the proxy server.
  - the package server or network connection is slow.
    If you are getting time out errors you can try setting the
    PKG_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT and PKG_CLIENT_READ_TIMEOUT
    environment variables and try again. For example to increase
    the timeouts to 300 seconds set them to 300
  - the package server is down or otherwise inaccessible or it is
    generating invalid data. Please contact the provider of the package
    server.
```

Error text example 2:

File 138/564 Input/output error: Connection failed for URL http: //pkg.oracle.com/javaeesdk/7/native/release/file/0/217e83782a91f09fa7f35122412cd155263b107f: 502: Proxy Error

```
Could not download application packages. This could be because:
  - a proxy server is needed to access the internet. Please ensure that
    the system proxy server settings are correct, or set the 'http_proxy'
    environment variable to the full URL of the proxy server.
  - the package server or network connection is slow.
    If you are getting time out errors you can try setting the
    PKG_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT and PKG_CLIENT_READ_TIMEOUT
    environment variables and try again. For example to increase
    the timeouts to 300 seconds set them to 300
  - the package server is down or otherwise inaccessible or it is
    generating invalid data. Please contact the provider of the package
    server.
```

I don't use any proxy server. Help please!

Comment: if you find the example files go to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633537/java-7-ee-tutorial-examples/44612105#44612105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same - it's because their site is so unbelievably slow.

The output you showed tells you what to do, increase the timeout.

But sometimes it just needs to be run again, which worked in my case.

Comment: @experimenter: I know, that this is really a shame how a site from a company like Oracle can be so unreliable. Your only chance is to try it again some other time or try to contact the tutorial team and ask for a direct download, which I was not able to find yet.

Comment: yes, it's not very nice when something like this happens. Thanks for support :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the tutorial from Oracle Java EE 7 SDK [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html).

Just download the latest Java EE 7 SDK, and unzip. The tutorial is inside the glassfish4/docs folder.

Comment: It wasn't inside at the moment question was asked. My question is about the installation of updatetools, not particularly the tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to install updatetool finally, after 3 days.

My advice for everyone who has the same problem:

Try installation several times in the morning, afternoon, evening and at night. And maybe once you will have successful attempt :)

The problem was not on my side.